# Where can I find the .whl file for Scipy (Gohlke only seems to give .zip files and these do not contain .whl files)?

Tags: python, python-wheel

I try to download the .whl file from gohlke (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs). In the past, I have always been able to do this.
I then installed the relevant package via PIP.

However, I now only seem to be able to download ZIP files with the whole package, instead of the .whl file. In the package that I can download, I am unable to find the .whl file.

I am trying to get scipy. I took the following steps:
1)      Create folder ‘C:\Scipy’
2)     I downloaded the package from gohlke (I use python 3.4.1, 32 bit, so I downloaded scipy-0.16.1-cp34-none-win32 to folder C:\Scipy)
3)     I opened the command window in C:\Scipy and give the following command:

pip install scipy-0.16.1-cp34-none-win32.whl

I get an error message stating that:

Requirement ‘scipy-0.16.1-cp34-none-win32.whl’ looks like a filename , but the file does not exist.

(I already expected this, since I do not see a .whl file in the ZIP I downloaded and extracted in C:\Scipy)

Who can tell me what I am doing wrong? Where can I find the .whl file that I need?

Kr,

Comment: @s0upa1t this is probably a Very stupid question, but what do you mean with ' you have to usedirect click on the right position'?

Comment: @s0upa1t thx. I did that. I still saves a zip file, no .whl to be found.

Answer (score 0):

rename the zip file with extension as .whl
There's your whl file... :)